# Minor bugfixes and adjustments for the TOC of classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) and prepared my document with `parts`, `chapters` and `sections`. This produces the following **table of contents**.

[image: TOC]

There are some details that I would like to fix:

1. Longer `part` numbers run into the `part` name. (highlighted in red)
2. I would like to manipulate the distance between subsequent `chapter` entries (highlighted in green). Thus, `chapter` entries followed by `section` entries should not be affected. (highlighted in yellow)
3. `Part` entries should have a dotted line as `sections` have.
4. The font size of the page number for `parts`, `chapters` and `sections` should be adjustable.

Last but not least, here is the MWE to test things out.

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, titlepage, dottedtoc, numbers=noenddot, 
headinclude, footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, BCOR=5mm, 
paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, ngerman] {scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,kantlipsum}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,      % false: boxed links; true: colored links.
    linktocpage=true,     % Moves the clickable link to the page numbers.
    linkcolor=OliveGreen  % Color of internal links.
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Baden-Württemberg} \chapter{Stuttgart} \chapter{Mannheim}
\part{Bayern} \chapter{Muenchen} \chapter{Nuernberg}

\part{Berlin}
\chapter{Berlin}
\section{Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf}\clearpage
\section{Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg}\clearpage
\section{Lichtenberg}\clearpage
\section{Marzahn-Hellersdorf}\clearpage
\section{Mitte}\clearpage
\section{Neukoelln}\clearpage
\section{Pankow}\clearpage
\section{Reinickendorf}\clearpage
\section{Spandau}\clearpage
\section{Steglitz-Zehlendorf}\clearpage
\section{Tempelhof-Schoeneberg}\clearpage
\section{Treptow-Koepenick}\clearpage

\part{Brandenburg} \chapter{Potsdam} \chapter{Cottbus}
\part{Bremen} \chapter{Bremen}
\part{Hamburg} \chapter{Hamburg}
\part{Hessen} \chapter{Wiesbaden} \chapter{Frankfurt}
\part{Mecklenburg-Vorpommern} \chapter{Schwerin} \chapter{Rostock}
\part{Niedersachsen} \chapter{Hannover} \chapter{Braunschweig}
\part{Nordrhein-Westfalen} \chapter{Duesseldorf} \chapter{Koeln}
\part{Rheinland-Pfalz} \chapter{Mainz} \chapter{Ludwigshafen}
\part{Saarland} \chapter{Saarbruecken}
\part{Sachsen} \chapter{Dresden} \chapter{Leipzig}
\part{Sachsen-Anhalt}\chapter{Magdeburg}\chapter{Halle}
\part{Schleswig-Holstein}\chapter{Kiel}\chapter{Luebeck}
\part{Thüringen} \chapter{Erfurt} \chapter{Jena}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Read the `classicthesis` manual before you are doing this. It breach with the package philosophy and intended layout.

Comment: @Sveinung Sorry, but maybe I am using the package the wrong way. I opened a [separate discussion on how to use classicthesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70690/how-to-use-classicthesis).

Comment: A related (but IMO not duplicate) question about [adjusting the TOC of classichesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138822/14210).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classicthesis` internally uses the `tocloft` package to design the ToC, so you can easily achieve what you want; all you have to do is to play with

- `\cftbeforechapskip` to change vertical skip before chapters.
- `\cftpartpagefont` to change the font for part page numbers.
- `\cftchappagefont` to change the font for chapter page numbers.
- `\cftsecpagefont` to change the font for section page numbers.
- `\cftpartdotsep` to control the leaders for part entries.
- `\cftpartaftersnumb` to add space between part number.

A little example illustrating the use of those lenghts/commands:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, titlepage, dottedtoc, numbers=noenddot, 
headinclude, footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, BCOR=5mm, 
paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, ngerman] {scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,kantlipsum}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,      % false: boxed links; true: colored links.
    linktocpage=true,     % Moves the clickable link to the page numbers.
    linkcolor=OliveGreen  % Color of internal links.
}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.1em} % change vertical skip before chapters
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\Large}% change the font for part page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large}% change the font for chapter page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\Large}% change the font for section page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% add leaders for part entries
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\normalfont\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftpartdotsep}
}% change the font for part leader dots (not boldfaced)
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\hspace*{0.5em}}% add space between part number and part title

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Baden-Württemberg} \chapter{Stuttgart} \chapter{Mannheim}
\part{Bayern} \chapter{Muenchen} \chapter{Nuernberg}

\part{Berlin}
\chapter{Berlin}
\section{Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf}\clearpage
\section{Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg}\clearpage
\section{Lichtenberg}\clearpage
\section{Marzahn-Hellersdorf}\clearpage
\section{Mitte}\clearpage
\section{Neukoelln}\clearpage
\section{Pankow}\clearpage
\section{Reinickendorf}\clearpage
\section{Spandau}\clearpage
\section{Steglitz-Zehlendorf}\clearpage
\section{Tempelhof-Schoeneberg}\clearpage
\section{Treptow-Koepenick}\clearpage

\part{Brandenburg} \chapter{Potsdam} \chapter{Cottbus}
\part{Bremen} \chapter{Bremen}
\part{Hamburg} \chapter{Hamburg}
\part{Hessen} \chapter{Wiesbaden} \chapter{Frankfurt}
\part{Mecklenburg-Vorpommern} \chapter{Schwerin} \chapter{Rostock}
\part{Niedersachsen} \chapter{Hannover} \chapter{Braunschweig}
\part{Nordrhein-Westfalen} \chapter{Duesseldorf} \chapter{Koeln}
\part{Rheinland-Pfalz} \chapter{Mainz} \chapter{Ludwigshafen}
\part{Saarland} \chapter{Saarbruecken}
\part{Sachsen} \chapter{Dresden} \chapter{Leipzig}
\part{Sachsen-Anhalt}\chapter{Magdeburg}\chapter{Halle}
\part{Schleswig-Holstein}\chapter{Kiel}\chapter{Luebeck}
\part{Thüringen} \chapter{Erfurt} \chapter{Jena}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as **Sveinung** notes in his remark, the author of `classicthesis` carefully and intentionally designed the package to produce the intended layout, so one has to be careful not to break the overall design.

To prevent a single section entry from appearing in a page (as is the case for "Frankfurt", in the example) one can say

```
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}}
```

for example right after `\chapter{Stuttgart}`.

Comment: Argument accepted. Still some issues such as the missing space should be fixed. - 1) Can you please add how I could **harmonize the size of the dots**? 2 Is there a way to **wrap TOC items** to the next page so that in your example "Franfurt" is not left alone on  the second page? - Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JJD Can you please tell me which missing space are you talking about? Regarding your other requests, I updated my answer.

Comment: I meant the space that I highlighted with the red color in my screenshot. - Thank you for the additional help!

Comment: @JJD in my answer I added `0.5em` with the line `\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\hspace*{0.5em}}`; if you need more spacing, use a larger length. Maybe I still don't get what space is causing the problem?

Comment: You already solved the problem in the first attempt. I am totally happy.

Comment: @JJD Ah, OK. I misunderstood you and I thought that my answer was incomplete.