# Doubts for customize classicthesis

Tags: babel, best-practices, classicthesis

I downloaded the `classicthesis` from its site and I was analysing the contents of the class, the manual, examples and all that. But I have few doubts yet about how to customize well the classic thesis class for my needs.

First of all I need to use the options `spanish` and `mexico` for `babel`. I read about the `es-lcroman` option necessary for write in Spanish, but I'm not sure if it works fine with the option `mexico`or there is not a problem.

Well, reading the `classic-thesisconfig.tex` document I found a lot of option, and a very interesting way to create a preamble. I use to divide my documents and use `\include` commands for add them, but the options of the preamble in another document looks nice.

However, I don't know how to fix few problems, the first of all is that I don't use the `natbib`package for my references, instead I prefer to use biblatex. Now, I see in classicthesis we can use a command `\PassOptionsToPackage{arg1}{arg2}` and I understand that `arg1` are the options of the package, and `arg2` the name of the own package. But I'm not sure why it uses this instead the old `\usepackage` command. I also don't know if I need to use the `\PassOptionsToPackage` for load each package?

I'm using the KOMA script class `scrbook`,using `letterpaper` size and I want to know if with classic thesis I can still use the options of the class such as the `\dictum` environment or `\lowertittleback` or `\dedication` because for me there are very useful.

In fact I need to create a document in Spanish, with few margin notes in polythonic Greek, English, German, Dutch and French. And the packages I'm using are:

```
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm} % My doubt is how to add the other packages in addition of amsmath?
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Instead of `acronym` I want to use the package `glossaries` for create the acronym list, a glossary and a list of symbols.

For graphics in addition to the `graphicx` package I need also this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
```

Where and how put it?

And for the revisions before finish the thesis I need to use

```
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
```

I know about the problems with biblatex and Greek but I'll find a way to solve it, (surely with `xelatex`) meanwhile I want to know how to add these package for work using the classicthesis style.

I have another final doubt, inside the `classicthesis-config.tex` document there is a part about autoreferences, I don't understand for what this can be useful but I see there is a redefinition of commands for English and German. So if I need to write in Spanish should I translate this commands into Spanish also or simply comment them?

An attempt of MWE for illustrate better my question, starting from the   `classicthesis.tex` file would be:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=5mm,paper=letter,fontsize=10pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
            spanish,mexico,%
            ]{scrbook}
\input{classicthesis-config} % where are part of my troubles
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{spanish} % <--- this isn't redundant?
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\frontmatter %All the following files previously customized
\include{FrontBackmatter/DirtyTitlepage}
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titlepage}
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titleback}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Dedication}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Foreword}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Abstract}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Publication}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Acknowledgments}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Contents}

\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage
%\part{Some stuff}
\include{Chapters/Chapter01}
\cleardoublepage
%\part{The Showcase}
\include{Chapters/Chapter02}
\include{Chapters/Chapter03}

%etc.

\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\part{Appendix}
\include{Chapters/Chapter0A}

\backmatter

\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Bibliography}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Colophon}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Declaration}
\end{document}
```

I think that's all. Regards.

Comment: I had to do this decision as well. In the end I decided against classicthesis, although it looks nice, because I needed to customize my template in a way, which would have been difficult to do with classicthesis and build it according to my needs using komascript.

Comment: Word of advice, pick out the pieces you like and don't look at the coding. It is just horrible. No matter what academic degree the author has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid we have different ideas about the organization of ClassicThesis.

It's disputable recommending to say

```
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titlepage}
```

Reason 1: why putting together frontmatter and backmatter material? Just because Miede likes doing that?

Reason 2: why `\include`, where `\input` would be the command of choice?

Of course, reason 2 is the main objection: `\include` adds reading one more auxiliary file for nothing, as it's quite unlikely you have cross references in your title page.

About `\PassOptionsToPackage` I can only say one thing: ***don't use it***. In the `config` file we find

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}                          

%\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 \usepackage{babel}                                     

\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}                            

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}           % math environments and more by the AMS 
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```

that's simply doing complicated things instead of easy ones. Here's a simplified version.

```
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"               

\usepackage[
  %ngerman,
  american,
  %spanish,es-lcroman,% es-lcroman is needed for this template
]{babel}                                     

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}                            

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

Isn't this version simpler? I bet so.

---

If you don't want `natbib` just leave it out. You're not compelled to use *that* `classicthesis-config*` file. The same for `acronym`.

The `config` file is used by way of example. Just say

```
\usepackage[
  eulerchapternumbers,
  listings,
  %drafting,
  pdfspacing,
  %floatperchapter,
  %linedheaders,
  %subfig,
  beramono,
  eulermath,
  parts
]{classicthesis}
```

and add after this the packages you need. Of course you can choose different options for ClassicThesis.

Comment: Thanks @egreg four your suggestions. Well, in fact my own way of organize a LaTeX document is different from the Miede's one. But I found an [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70690/how-to-use-classicthesis) where praising how Miede divided parts of the text in all those files you see in his examples. In my opinion the FrontBackMatter directory is where everything extra to main content (main matter) goes. I use with `book` and `scrbook` classes the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` they ease few tasks.

Comment: Well, I follow your suggestions and I changed all the `\PassOptionsToPackage` in the `classicthesis-config.tex`file and now nothing works \m/.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `\PassOptionsToPackage` is used is compatibility with LyX: if a package is loaded with options both in LyX and `-config.tex` a clash occurs and the document is not compilable. It seemed better to have the template compilable as-is by using `\PassOptionsToPackage`, even though it would lead to some options not being evaluated.

As reference, see the TeX FAQ [Option clash for package](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash).

Comment: Hi and welcome, this doesn't andwer the question and is more like a comment on @egregs answer. I guess a moderator will convert this answer soon.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason; but it confirms me that LyX does things in the wrong way.