# Improvements on table of contents in classicthesis

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis` for my master degree dissertation and I'm having very hard time to make table of content more pleasing. What I have right now is this:

[image]

and what I'm trying to achieve is a basic simple toc (something like the image below)

[image]

To be more precise, I don't want any `all caps`, bold face on chapter title and finally, proportional font size (contrary of what is now).

Any guidelines or starting point for someone who is not a master of renewing commands?

P.S. I like the title of the page (allcaps surrounded by lines) and the font of toc and I prefer not to change them.

P.P.S. I'm using `classicthesis` with the following options:

```
\usepackage[linedheaders,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
```

Comment: If you use Classicthesis, you are not supposed to modify the proposed settings that are based on Tufte's recommendations. The question is: why are you using Classicthesis if you want to modify the ToC (and maybe more)?

Comment: @pluton, your point is *fairly* valid. The point is I like `classicthesis` and I like to use it but I find that toc drastically ugly (I might be wrong knowing that I'm not a typesetting master/artist. But as a user, I have personal preferences).

Comment: I think classicthesis relies on [**`tocloft`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft) for typesetting the table of contents. Perhaps you can customize it. Try to change `\cftchapfont`, etc. (I really can't try it right now)

Comment: @henrique, thank you so much for actually answering the quation. In fact I'm working on it. I had some success by using `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}`. The problem is now everything is all lower-cased. But thanks again.

Comment: The problem of LaTeX lower-casing the TOC entries seems to lead back to a missing font. At least this is the warning that my machine gives me.

Comment: @Pouya, classicthesis redefines `\chapter` in a way that if sets the toc entry (`\chapter`'s optional argument) in `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, which, among other (typographically beautiful) things, issues `\MakeTextLowercase`. Try to redefine it to `\renewcommand\Chap[2][]{\oldchap[#1]{#2}}`

Comment: Maybe you could give a look at ArsClassica which is based on classicthesis... This is what I did personally. Mixing the two (basically keeping classicthesis font) will give you a really nice result.

Comment: A related (but IMO not duplicate) question about [adjusting the TOC of classichesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70672/14210).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classicthesis` relies on the [**`tocloft`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft) package to typeset the table of contents. `tocloft` provides several macros to control the appearance of the entries; you should start by changing them. As suggested by Ruben, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

But this won't suffice to remove the small caps formatting from chapter entries because `classicthesis` redefines `\chapter` adding its own `\spacedlowsmallcaps` (which involves a `\MakeTextLowercase`) to its very contents-line, by issuing something like (I simplified it a lot):

```
\let\oldchap=\chapter
...
\oldchap[\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}]{#2}
```

So, in order to solve this, all you have to do is to redefine it by renewcommand its local chapter command, `\Chap`:

```
\renewcommand\Chap[2][]{\oldchap[#1]{#2}}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis,mwe}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand\Chap[2][]{\oldchap[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 2):

Basically you only need to switch a few fonts. As the comments say, this can be achived through `tocloft` by adding

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
```

to your preamble (and loading the tocloft package, trivially). Now you want that dot (like in the second pic). Unfortunatelly `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}` does not work for me. So here is the equivalent approach using `titletoc`:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\vspace{.75em}\sffamily\bfseries}%
{\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel.\hspace{.5em}]{3em}}
{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{.5em}]
```

Finally there is the lower-casing-issue, which can be eliminated by adding the "nochapters" option to the package-setup, i.e. `\usepackage[linedheaders,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,nochapters]{classicthesis}`. The other way would be to select a font that supports the bold sans-serif and lower case situation:

```
%\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{pag}
%\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{phv}
%\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{pbk}
%\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{pnc}
```

Uncomment the one you like best. The "drawback" of using the nochapters option is a minimally changed layout, as far as i can see. Furtermore the fontfamilies mentioned above do not look nice in that context. So i suggest to go with the option-option and not with the fonts.

### Edit

You can easily solve the latter problem by adding

```
\let\Chap\oldchap
```

to the preamble without activating the nochapters-option.